# Run lessc through Node - not Bundler

Tags: bundler, less, npm

Got a bit of a pickle of a question - I'm sure fairly straight forward if I just knew the correct way to ask Google.

I've been getting the hang of LESS lately and originally installed it globally through NPM, i.e. `npm install lessc -g` to use with an [initializer](http://www.initializr.com/) project - running `lessc less/style.less style.css` like a champ before I deploy it off my local computer.

Loving it - working great - decide to use LESS with a separate rails project - add the `gem 'less-rails'` to the project - `bundle install` - get it rolling and working smoothly.

Unfortunately now that I've gone back to my initializer project - `lessc less/style.less style.css` throws an error message that references RVM and Bulder.

Eventually I found a workaround by installing LESSC locally with `npm install lessc -g` and running `node_modules/less/bin/lessc less/style.less style.css` but this is a pain.

**So:** How do I get LESSC back to working exclusively with Node and ignoring all that RVM / Ruby / Bundler crap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I was able to do this by adding a variable to my `.bash_profile` file in my user directory that pointed at the global node installation of LESS.

Basically adding

`export lessc=~/.npm/less/1.3.0/package/bin/lessc`

to `.bash_profile` or `.profile` or `.bashrc` in your user directory. And running `source ~/.bash_profile`.